# "Real" cardinality, say, $\aleph_\pi$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, infinity

Is there any meaningful definition to afford for $\aleph_r$ (as in cardinality) where $r\in\mathbb{R}^+$? $r\in\mathbb{C}$? What about $\aleph_{\aleph_0}$? Can we iterate this? $\aleph_{\aleph_{\aleph_{\cdots}}}$

I may be throwing in bunch of rather naive/basic questions, for I haven't learnt much about infinite cardinalities. If I am referring to bunch of stuff abundantly dealt in established areas, please kindly point out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The $\aleph$ numbers are well-ordered. This means that every non-empty set has a minimal element. Furthermore, they are *linearly* ordered.

This means that any indexing imposed on them should at least have these two properties. The real numbers are not well-ordered (consider the subset $(0,1)$, or even $\mathbb R$ itself) and the complex numbers are not even ordered in any natural sense.

The idea behind having a well-ordering is to say what is the next cardinality. Given a set, we can easily tell what is the least $\aleph$ which is larger. In the natural numbers (and their generalization, the ordinals) we have a successor function which does that, so it is a good ground to use when indexing cardinalities. We don't have a nice successor function for the real numbers, or for any dense ordering for a matter of fact.

It is possible to have $\aleph_{\aleph_0}$, but there is a minor problem here. $\aleph_0$ is the notation discussing *size*, whereas $\aleph_\alpha$ is the cardinal that the cardinals below it have order type $\alpha$. So we write $\aleph_\omega$, where $\omega$ is the least infinite ordinal. This is a *limit* cardinal, which means that it is not a successor of any cardinal -- but there are smaller $\aleph$'s nonetheless.

This of course can be reiterated, but we need to use the *ordinal* form, rather the cardinal form. Namely, every $\aleph$ number is also an ordinal. $\aleph_\alpha$ is the actually the ordinal $\omega_\alpha$, where these ordinals are defined recursively as ordinals which are $(1)$ infinite; and $(2)$ do not have an injection into any smaller ordinal. The least is $\aleph_0$ and it is the cardinality of the natural numbers, which is the ordinal $\omega$.

So if we wish to iterate, $\aleph_0\to\aleph_{\aleph_0}\to\aleph_{\aleph_{\aleph_0}}\to\dots$ we actually need to do it as following: $$\aleph_0\to\aleph_{\omega}\to\aleph_{\omega_\omega}\to\ldots$$

---

That been said, without the axiom of choice it is consistent to have sets whose cardinality is *not* an $\aleph$ number, namely sets which cannot be well-ordered. It is consistent that there is a collection of sets which is ordered (by inclusion) like the real numbers, and no two sets have the same cardinality (there is no bijection between two distinct sets).

---

**Some threads which may interest the reader:**

1. ["Homomorphism" from set of sequences to cardinals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15162)
2. [Non-aleph infinite cardinals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172316)
3. [What are Aleph numbers intuitively?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202727)

Comment: Set theorists abuse the notation, though, don't they?  For example, they might speak of the fixed point of the $x\mapsto \aleph_x$ function, when what they really mean is the fixed point of the function that takes an ordinal $x$ to the smallest ordinal with cardinality $\aleph_x$.  Or is there some other way to say this?

Comment: @MJD: Th class of cardinals is definable, so it is not really an abuse of notation. The fixed point issue is simply to say that there are $\alpha$ cardinals (as an order type) below $\alpha$.

Comment: @MJD: Did my edit answer your question better?

Comment: What does $\aleph_{\omega_\omega}$ mean?

Comment: @MJD: The unique initial ordinal such that the order type of the initial ordinals below it is as the ordinal $\omega_\omega$. Alternatively we can say that this is the least $\aleph$ for which there are $\aleph_\omega$ strictly smaller cardinals.

Comment: What is the ordinal $\omega_\omega$?

Comment: @MJD: It is the initial ordinal such that the order type of the initial ordinals smaller than it is $\omega$; alternatively the smallest initial ordinal such that the set of initial ordinals smaller than it is unbounded.